# Can't animate my NSMutableArray from AppDelegate

Tags: arrays, xcode, animation, nsmutablearray, appdelegate

I'm creating an array in my AppDelegate and then want to use it in another view controller (repeat continuously until I close the view).  It populates the array, but doesn't seem to animate.  I've searched and made edits for days.  Any help would be appreciated!

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *sharedArray1;
@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "Scene1.h"
@synthesize sharedArray1;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions  {

int ii;

for (ii = 1; ii<70;)   {     
    [sharedArray1 addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"RadarCircle_Active%i.png", ii] ofType:nil]]]];
    NSLog(@"Log RadarCircle_Active i: %i",ii);
    ii = ii + 1;  // increment by 1
}

return YES;
}
```

Scene1.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

-(void)radarActive{

float duration1 = 5.5;

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
activeRadarImage.animationImages = appDelegate.sharedArray1;
activeRadarImage.animationDuration = duration1;
//    activeClawImage.animationRepeatCount = count;
[activeRadarImage startAnimating];  
}
```

Comment: Is `activeRadarImage` non-nil?

Comment: It's the image name.  should it be of type "png"?

Comment: When you're having problems like this, step through the code in the debugger and make sure everything is non-nil. (And use temporary variables instead of long, chained expressions). And for `pathForResource:ofType:`, the `ofType` is there for a reason, you should use `pathForResource:@"foo" ofType:@"png"`, not `pathForResource:@"foo.png" ofType:nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @architectpianist said you need to allocate first and try changing

```
[sharedArray1 addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"RadarCircle_Active%i.png", ii] ofType:nil]]]];
```

to

```
[sharedArray1 addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"RadarCircle_Active%i", ii] ofType:@"png"]]]];
```

Or u can do it this way

```
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"RadarCircle_Active%i.png", ii];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
NSLog(@"image : %@", image);
[sharedArray1 addObject:image];
```

Check out the NSLog.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you need to set `sharedArray1` to something before you start adding objects to it.

Try adding this before you start the loop:

```
self.sharedArray1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```